# Dropzone: Global Events and Custom Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am searching for a solution to handle my own messages which are inserted as sticky elements on the top of the page instead of the dropzone ones according to the preview-template for each file in the dropzone-container.

My problem is, that I remove invalid files and when the user selects 100 files and maximum 20 are allowed, 80 files are removed from the dropzone-container, but also 80 error messages blow up my screen. At this point, I am not interested which file and why it can't be uploaded.

Is there something like a global dropzone-event that is called only once if a condtition is true or another possibilty to handle this?

```
dropzone.on("complete", function (file) {
    if (!file.accepted){
        dropzone.removeFile(file);
        Messages.showError("Some files are not valid and have been removed ");
    }
});
```

Comment: have you trolled the events doc on the dropzone site http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list , rather than run your Message.show above why not set a variable so if any fail set it to true then on `successmultiple`event check if its true and then output message

Comment: problem is, that "successmultiple" is called, when the upload is finished. i set "autoProcessQueue: false", so none of these events are called until the user clicks the upload-button. the idea is good, but the right event is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `maxfilesreached` you can do

```
dropzone.on("maxfilesreached",
 function (file) {
        Messages.showError("Some files are not valid and have been removed ");
);
```

But I think the Dropzone sanctioned way is to set the event in the `init`

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
  maxFiles: 20,
  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log("all uploaded");
    done();
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on("maxfilesreached", function(file){
         Messages.showError("Some files are not valid and have been removed   ");
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: sadly this does not work, since "maxfilesexceeded" is also triggered for every file which is added to the container. this would also only handle the maxFiles, not invalid files whereas 'file.accepted' is false even if the limit was reached or an invalid filetype was added :/

Comment: how about `maxfilesreached`?

Comment: "maxfilesreached" is also under the section with the header "All of these receive the file as first parameter" - so it is called for every file that is added.